# corona physics - different mass object?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics, gravity

this is what i'm trying to do, 2 balls will drop at different height, their bounce is set to 1.0, which means after bounce they will go back to their original position. But the higher ball will drop and bounce faster than the lower ball, so when the higher ball bounces and goes back to it's original position once, the lower ball finishes its first bounce too.

is ok that they don't bounce once at the same time?  i just want to know how i can change their speed.

so far what i have found is that we can't change their mass, density won't effect drop speed, set gravity will effect both. any solution please?

Comment: When you say the "higher ball", do you mean the ball with greater mass, or the ball that is higher from the ground?

Comment: sry for not clear enough for my question, the ball is higher from the ground.

Comment: and i'm trying to change the mass of those ball, so the ball that higher from the ground can drop faster

Answer (score 3):

> and i'm trying to change the mass of those ball, so the ball that higher from the ground can drop faster

Heavier things do not fall faster. Either in reality or a proper simulation thereof. The reason why we think of heavy things falling faster is because of air resistance. Objects moving through the air have resistance from that air, and this slows down light objects more than heavier ones.

So you would either have to break the physics system or implement air resistance.

Comment: yea... i have do some research and knowing that heavier things wont fall faster even in reality, but still i'll need this.

what i'm trying to do is a game, before the game start player will need to choose a ball that slower, or a ball that faster. so i want them to keep bouncing at the choosing page. either make 1 ball faster or another slower will do. After player choose the ball, i'll just simply change the gravity or setscale when in game.